# sed doesn't work with variables to replace text in files

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace string of all js files exsting in directories

```
export name="test_user" &&
echo $customerName &&
sed -i -- 's/this.NAME=""/this.NAME=\"'$name'\"/g' *.js
```

If I don't use space it works fine  but with string above command fails

Comment: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
's/this\.NAME=""/this.NAME="'"$name"'"/g'
```

Broken down into parts:

1. `'s/this\.NAME=""/this.NAME="'`
2. `"$name"`, this is the important bit: the variable expansion must be quoted.
3. `'"/g'`

Also, if you use `\"` in the replacement, and it's in single quotes, then you would insert `\"`, not `"`, into the result.

You also seem to use a variable called `customerName`. I'm assuming this is a typo.

Whether the `sed` that you are using can do in-place editing in the way that you seem to want to do, I don't know.

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: Whether `'s/x/\"/'` replaces `x` with `"` or `\"` or anything else is unspecified by POSIX but in practice I find that most implementations (all those I tried) replace `x` with `"`, not `\"`.